# Не получается вставить html в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ругается на первую строчку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуста

```js
var inhtml = "<table style='width:100%;'>
       <tr>
           <td class='zz2_girl'><img src='{THEME}/images/girl.png' alt=''></td>
           <td>
            <form method='post' action='form2.php'>
               <div class='zz2_title'>Хотите найти тур своей мечты?</div>
               <div class='zz3_title'>Давайте мы перезвоним вам в течении 5 минут и предложим лучшие туры под ваши пожелания</div>
               <input class='modal_form' type='text' name='phone' placeholder='ваш Телефон'>
               <button type='button' class='zz_4 f_send_mail'>Жду звонка</button>

                <a data-dismiss='modal' type='button' class='close-reveal-modal zz_4 close_popup'>ок. жду</a>
               </form>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
<br><br>

<a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var inhtml = "<table style='width:100%;'>
> ```

```
var inhtml = "<table style='width:100%;'>\
```

И остальные строки аналогично.